# Для игрового сервера какой подойдет VPS?

Tags: linux, windows, сервер, администрирование, vps

Для игрового сервера какой подойдет VPS?

Игровой сервер надо для игр типо CS:GO, Dota2

Какой из этих выбрать?

*openVZ Servers

*KVM Servers

*Windows Servers

P.S. Вообще какие ещё бывают?

Comment: А ты у себя на локальном компе на linux поднимал? Всё работало?

Comment: Не openvz точно, остальное надо изучать конкретные требования конкретной игры и конкретные технические возможности и правила конкретного хостинга (некоторые запрещают высокую нагрузку надолго создавать)

Comment: @andreymal, я так понимаю, что нужен dedical server. а не просто vps...